# I can't run my applet in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

When I try to run my applet in NetBeans it tells me that there is no main class. I looked it up and others have had this error, but they don't give great instructions how to fix it. I tried going to Properties > Application > Web Start and changing it to Applet descriptor with my applet class. But, it still doesn't work, and I don't know why. can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the run configuration in the toolbar to Web Start:

[image]

Now when you click run, it will run the applet.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try putting in a main class that simply does nothing.
2. If you have two different classes for this one applet, make sure you are running the one that has a main, only one needs one.
3. As far as "selecting your applet as the main class" I don't have a clue what that means either.

Hope I've been helpful, I'm new to the whole graphics thing (for java, anyway) too!

If this problem persists, please elaborate!

Comment: I don't want to create a main class, I just want an applet and there is a way to do it I just don't know how. That is why i asked on here.

Comment: Just to clarify, it says "no main class" not "no main method" right?

Comment: Yes, it says no main class. I'm sorry for the confusion.